Is proof by cases mathematically unsound?
In this question, the questioner had a Discrete Math test coming up, and had been studying religiously. Now, the answer points out that $$((P \implies R) \land (Q \implies R)) \quad\implies\quad ((P \lor Q) \implies R).$$
So, letting...
$P\ =\ $"I will pass my Discrete Math test,"
$Q\ =\ $"I will not pass my Discrete Math test," and
$R\ =\ $"asking Stack Exchange for help preparing is superfluous,"
...the questioner could have concluded arguing by cases that asking Stack Exchange for help preparing was superfluous (assuming the test was pass/fail, no value was placed on learning for its own sake, etc.).
I think this is related to Simpson's Paradox and/or Newcomb's Paradox, and the problem comes from the fact that asking Stack Exchange for help preparing has causal impact on the boundary between Case $P$ and Case $Q$.  However, in actual Math classes/presentations/videos/book/etc., I never see care being taken to assess whether this impact is present when handling cases.  Indeed, the Wikipedia article for proof by cases says nothing about it.
Should proof by cases be demoted from rigorous mathematical proof technique to heuristic, or am I missing some observation that rescues it?

$P \implies R$ and $Q \implies R$ are both false. It seems that you  are trying to interpret $P$ as "I will pass my test no matter what", which is a different statement. It can be formalized using modal logic.

Every assertion is always with respect to a fixed (and tacit) interpretation and background assumptions. Once this is agreed on, statements like "asking for help is superfluous" $(R)$ and "I will pass my test" in propositional logic (which doesn't claim to handle non-logical predictions) are each simply either true or false (that future tense is a red herring). Is $R$ actually true or false?; if True, the following argument is sound; otherwise, it is valid but unsound:
$$P \implies R\
Q \implies R\
\text{_____________________}\
\therefore\quad (P \lor Q) \implies R.$$

For the people voting to close for "Needs details or clarity," what other details need to be added?  I don't mind editing the question, but the question has been understood and an answer given already, so it's not clear what else should be stated.

The reason we believe $P \implies R$ is that, we are interpreting $P$ as "I will pass the test, no matter what actions I take before the test." Otherwise I don't see how you can conclude $R$. Therefore the negation of $P$ should be "I am not guaranteed to pass the test", which is not equal to $Q$.
This can be formalized with modal logic. What we are really trying to say is $\square P \implies R$, where $\square$ is the necessity modality. And we can also say that $\square Q \implies R$. Also, $P = \neg Q$. Note that $\neg \square P$ is not the same as $\square Q = \square \neg P$! Indeed, we have $\neg \square P = \lozenge \neg P = \lozenge Q$, where $\lozenge$ is the possibility modality.
In conclusion, the reasoning is valid but not sound, in the sense that the logic is correct, but the premises are false.
